# Can I move the indicators in Bootstrap carousel to the right?

Tags: html

Is it possible to make the indicators in the Bootstrap carousel move to the right? 
Using `float: right;` doesn't really do anything. Neither does `position: relative; left: 300px;`.

Is there any way that I can move the indicators to the right?
What about moving them up?

Comment: I don't use bootstrap but how about position: absolute; top: 0; left 300px; Make sure position relative is on parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use custom css on the `.carousel-indicators{}` class, use `text-align: right;` to position the li elements and then set `right: 0;` and `left: inherit;`

```
.carousel-indicators {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    right: 2% !important;
    left: inherit;
}
```

Think [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/1bBNeU4giX#) is what your looking for.

Update: The reason its not working for you in your code is that you have the `boostrap.css` called after your `home.css` so it is overwriting the css you are trying to use to move the indicators.

This is how your `<head>` should look

```
<head>
    <title>project</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f86debf509.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @CRover are you sure you have images in, just tested with your code and it works as long as there are images http://www.bootply.com/UPmI8IwH3A

Comment: @CRover your code works in this http://www.bootply.com/UPmI8IwH3A you sure you have no other css effecting the carousel?

Comment: @CRover Figured it out the reason its not working for you is you have the boostrap css link after your custom css change the order of the css around

Answer (score 1):

In your code the header is covering up much of the carousel in narrower screens, possibly covering up your carousel-indicator.

Here's a fiddle that pushes the carousel down 75px.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/7n0pa1cq/

You can override the default css with this and position with right:

```
.carousel {
  /* position is already relative by bootstrap default */
  top: 75px; /* because your header is fixed and has a height of 75px; */ 
}
.carousel-indicators {
    width: initial; /* initial resets css to default */
    margin-left: initial;
    left: initial;
    bottom: initial;
    right: 10px; /*horizontal position */
    top: 100px; /* vertical position */
}
```

The reason your changes were only sort of working was because you were calling home.css before bootstraps css. Only the styles in home.css that weren't in bootstrap were affecting change, bootstrap css settings had the final word.

Putting home.css last will override bootstrap css.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f86debf509.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
```

Comment: @CRover If you can, maybe post your custom css so we can see if all is in order. It could be some tiny thing you've left in while throwing different things at it to try and affect change. (I do it all the time)

Comment: @CRover My bad, i didnt update the fiddle before I left. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/7n0pa1cq/ What was happening is the header was above the carousel, covering up the courosel-indicators on narrower screen widths.

Comment: @CRover Ahh, then that could be tricky. All I can suggest is to try a different browser if you're not already using the latest FF or Chrome. Also, is it possible you're caching an older version of your custom css file?

Comment: @CRover Ohh, home.css is your custom css? Put that last in the order in your head.

Comment: @CRover Ha, it's always something that simple, too many things are so easy to overlook like we both did there ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel: {
height: 100%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

And change the indicators' styles. You can adjust `right:30px`

```
.carousel-indicators {
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
right:30px;
z-index: 15;
width: 60%;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is bootstrap 5 though

````
   position: absolute;
   right: 0 !important;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 2;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   padding: 0;
   margin-right: 3% !important;
   left:unset !important;
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
} ```
````